# Resetting counter to zero

Tags: java

I'm currently learning Java.

I have a for loop which uses a counter to keep track of how many words are written on a line.

When the wordCount == 10, I insert a line break System.out.println()

I want to reset wordCount to zero after this line break, but redeclaring wordCount == 0 is "not a statement" in NetBeans. How do I reset a variable value? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah u can add a condition :

if ( wordcount ==10)
wordcount =0;

This will reinitialize wordcount to 0, when it becomes 10. Hope it helps.

We use '==' during comparison and '=' for assigning values.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
wordCount = 0;
```

Using the double equals sign `==` is *comparison*, while the single equals sign `=` is *assignment*.

Comment: Yep, that did it. Is == just for initialization?

Comment: No, `==` is for comparison, it's when you want to see whether the value of the variable equals something or not. You use the `=` for initialisation too.

Comment: Thank you, that was embarrassingly simple :D

Comment: Historically, the difference between `=` and `==` in C is something that can trip up even expert programmers!

Comment: Pascal-Users remember `:=` for assignment.